# How do you name output files using an increment after a bash file loop?

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, awk

I'm trying to treat a bunch of files (five) with an awk command and name the output files using an incrementation.
The input files have complicated names. I know how to reuse the files' basenames to rename the outputs but I want to simplify the file names.

this is my code:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    for i in {1..5}; do
        echo processing file $f
        awk '
            { if ($1=="something" && ($5=="60" || $5=="61"|| $5=="62"|| $5=="63"|| $5=="64"|| $5=="65"|| $5=="66"|| $5=="67"|| $5=="68"|| $5=="69"|| $5=="70"))
            print   }' $b.txt>"file_treated"$i.txt
        echo processing file $f over
    done
done
```

I understand that the error is in the second line because what I wrote runs the second loop for each value of the first one. I want each value of the first loop to correspond to one value of the second one.

Hope this was clear enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
i=0
for f in *.txt; do
    let i++;
    awk '$1=="something" && ($5 >= 60 && $5 <=70)' "$f" > file_treated"${i}".txt
done
```

I simplified your `awk` command and straightened out your various quoting issues. I also removed the `$b.txt` since you were simply recreating `$f`. I left the `echo $b` etc in case you actually wanted that but it could just as easily be replaced with `echo "$f"`.

Comment: yeah sorry about that, the $b stuff was left over from a previous version of the code. Could you tell me more about the quoting issues i.e why my quotes weren't correct?

Comment: @user22277 because they were absent :). You should always quote shell variables, for different reasons in different contexts but it's a good habit to get into. It i) protects special characters inside your variables from being interpreted by the shell and ii) protects against word splitting that is also often an issue. Here, if your file names contain spaces, most of your commands will break unless you've quoted the variable. I removed all of the `b` stuff since you said you don't needed. See updated answer.

Comment: Good advice to always quote variables. With that in mind: `... > "file_treated${i}.txt"`. Also, wrt `$5 >= 60 && $5 <="70"`, I don't think you need quotes around one number and not the other.

Comment: @EdMorton well, hoist by my own petard. In my defense, I copied both from the OP's original post :). Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Use a counter:

```
i=1
for f in *.txt
do
    echo "$f is number $((i++))"
done
```

Comment: Is something missing from your code? like an i++ at the end? I have to admit I still don't understand this. Wouldn't using a counter overwrite all the files everytime the counter increases in value?

Comment: Why would incrementing a number overwrite all files?

Comment: because for each value of i you're runnning the full for loop

Comment: @user22277 The loop only runs one iteration per text file.

Comment: @user22277 the `$((i++))` increments `$i` just after echo prints it. Try `i=0; echo $((i++)) $i`, it will return `0 1`.

Comment: Oh ok, I just wasn't aware of this syntax. is there a point to the double (())?